# How to get rid off html tags in JSF to return only JSON?

Tags: json, jsf

If I have the following only, what should I do to get only the jsf expression data output without any other stuff?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

#{backingBean.jsonData}

</html>
```

Comment: the documentation type and all  <!DOCTYPE html

Comment: are you accessing your bean properly, eg index.jsf ? do yopu by any chance see the source code of the page when you open in , instead of some real data , like seeing <h3>WOW</h3> instead just seeing WOW in big bold font?

Comment: If I open the page and see view source i can see the entire code which is listed here

Comment: How do you open it in browser ? localhost:8080/index.jsf or index.xhtml? (i;m not talking about the view - > source )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just don't output `<!DOCTYPE>` and `<html>` then.

```
<ui:composition xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
#{backingBean.jsonData}
</ui:composition>
```

That said, you're here basically abusing JSF, a component based MVC framework, as a JSON web service. This is a very bad design approach as in "using the wrong tool for the job". I strongly recommend to take a look at JAX-RS, which is the right tool for the job. Jersey has a very nice [tutorial](http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/user-guide.html).

Comment: I have no such experience with JAX-RS and how to do this with JAX-RS. Basically i need this to get data to front-end with jquery AJAX. If you know how to do it with JAX-RS Please help me out. Thanks for the answer I'll check this and inform the progress

Comment: Just click the tutorial link in my answer?

Comment: from this approach i lose all the data my jsf data is also blank

Comment: This works perfectly Thank you very much. It was my typing mistake which got rid off all the data